# Using Appcompatactivity with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, appcompatactivity

In a recent Android Developer [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) **appcompatactivity** is introduced. In the video it is said that if using Android Studio the min SDK is specified as 7, Android Studio automatically switches to appcompatactivity. However I've not been able to get this to work. In Android Studio v1.1 **actionbaractivity** was used which seems to have changed back to **activity** in Android Studio v1.2.

What am I missing?

Comment: Always extend `AppCompatActivity` when using the `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`.

Comment: Is there a way to get Android Studio to use AppCompatActivity automatically as they say in the video?

Comment: Just type it out. It is just a class.